# SQL MAX & GroupBy into LINQ VB?

Tags: vb.net, linq

have the following SQL query with table joins, a MAX over a date and Group By working from my DB.

```
SELECT [log].employee_id
      ,[log].trans_id
      ,[log].shift
      ,[log].operation
      ,max([log].post_date) as "Last Date Employee"
      ,TMD_Standard_Pcs.item
    ,Employees.name
    ,TMD_Standard_Pcs.TrainingMatrixNumber
  FROM [log]
  join TMD_Standard_Pcs 
  on part_number = item
  join employees
  on [log].employee_id = Employees.employee_id
  where [log].trans_id = 'wip' and [log].part_number = '16594CE'
  and [log].operation = 900
  group by [log].employee_id,[log]
  .trans_id,[log].shift
  ,[log].operation
  ,TMD_Standard_Pcs.item
  ,TMD_Standard_Pcs.TrainingMatrixNumber
  ,Employees.name
   order by employees.name
```

Sample result:

```html
5509| WIP| B| 900| 2014-09-18 00:00:00.000| 16594CE| ADAMS, AMANDA| F16594/95
```

I would like to convert this into LINQ to SQL for VB .NET.
Any ideas, I'm pretty new to LINQ and this seems complicated.

More Detail EDIT:
Three MS SQL server tables linked. Log table contains "many" logged records for each employee
jobbing ON and OFF of a specific part number during any given day. The TMD_Standard_PCS has a related Family part number which does not change called Training Matrix number. the employees table is used to pull in the actual employee's name as it relates to there clock number. There are NO keys over any of these tables. I did not design the DB, I just program against it. The system used for this is a labor tracking system.

Since employees can Log into and out of part numbers they accumulate records with identical field data values. so, my need here is to grab the **last** record for each employee by descending (max) date (group?) which could be today, last month, or even last year.

I have this basic LINQ code from LINQpad which shows all detail records.

```html
dim EmployeesbyJob = from lg in logs _
      join pcs in TMD_Standard_Pcs _
      on lg.part_number equals pcs.item _
      join emp in Employees _
      on lg.employee_id equals emp.employee_id _
      where lg.trans_id = "WIP" _
      and pcs.currentrevlevel = true _
      and lg.operation = 900 _
      and lg.part_number = "11740A"
      order by lg.part_number,emp.name,lg.post_date descending 
      select emp.name,pcs.TrainingMatrixNumber,lg.employee_id,lg.trans_id,lg.operation,lg.part_number,lg.post_date,lg.shift
```

```html
IOrderedQueryable<VB$AnonymousType_2<String,String,String,String,String,String,DateTime?,String>> (63 items)
name TrainingMatrixNumber employee_id trans_id operation part_number post_date shift
ADKINS, NATHAN F11739/40       3698 WIP 900 11740A 2/26/2009 12:00:00 AM 2
ADKINS, NATHAN F11739/40       3698 WIP 900 11740A 2/25/2009 12:00:00 AM 2
ADKINS, NATHAN F11739/40       3698 WIP 900 11740A 2/25/2009 12:00:00 AM 2
ADKINS, NATHAN F11739/40       3698 WIP 900 11740A 2/25/2009 12:00:00 AM 2
ADKINS, NATHAN F11739/40       3698 WIP 900 11740A 2/25/2009 12:00:00 AM 2
ANDERSON, MICHELLE F11739/40       2248 WIP 900 11740A 11/13/2009 12:00:00 AM 1
ARNOLD, JEREMY F11739/40       3723 WIP 900 11740A 9/16/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BAUKNECHT, STEVE F11739/40       2742 WIP 900 11740A 1/6/2010 12:00:00 AM 3
BAUKNECHT, STEVE F11739/40       2742 WIP 900 11740A 11/13/2009 12:00:00 AM 3
BAUKNECHT, STEVE F11739/40       2742 WIP 900 11740A 11/13/2009 12:00:00 AM 3
BAUKNECHT, STEVE F11739/40       2742 WIP 900 11740A 8/29/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BAUKNECHT, STEVE F11739/40       2742 WIP 900 11740A 8/29/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BIALECKI, BRYAN F11739/40       2064 WIP 900 11740A 1/6/2010 12:00:00 AM 3
BIALECKI, BRYAN F11739/40       2064 WIP 900 11740A 11/20/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BIALECKI, BRYAN F11739/40       2064 WIP 900 11740A 9/16/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BIALECKI, BRYAN F11739/40       2064 WIP 900 11740A 8/29/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BIALECKI, BRYAN F11739/40       2064 WIP 900 11740A 8/29/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BIALECKI, BRYAN F11739/40       2064 WIP 900 11740A 8/29/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BIALECKI, BRYAN F11739/40       2064 WIP 900 11740A 8/29/2008 12:00:00 AM 3
BOYER, MELANIE F11739/40       3811 WIP 900 11740A 1/5/2010 12:00:00 AM 2
BOYER, MELANIE F11739/40       3811 WIP 900 11740A 11/13/2009 12:00:00 AM 3
```

Comment: Please never just drop SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts.

Comment: My apologies, this is for LINQ to SQL, using MS SQL server DB tables. there are 3 tables joined. I will attempt to gather more information to clarify. Thank you for the tips.